# if $v$ is a member of $H$ and $v$ is not a member of $M$ then $u$ is member of $K$. How is this possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, mathematical-physics, topological-vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra

Let $(V,K)$ and $u,v$ is a member of $V$. Suppose that $M$ is a subset of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ with basis $B_m=\{m_1,...,m_r\}$ with $r$ less than and equal to $n$. Let $H$ be a subspace spanned by $B_m$ and $u$. Moreover, let $K$ be the subspace spanned by $B_m$ and $v$. Prove that if $v$ is a member of $H$ and $v$ is not a member of $M$ then $u$ is member of $K$.

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is not an element of $M$, then $K$ is one dimension larger than $M$ and contains $v$.  We know that $H$ is at most one dimension larger than $M$ and also contains $v$.  Thus $K=H$.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I want to show u is a member of K. I know that v is already

Comment: @Tiffany Ah, but $u\in H$ and I have shown that $H=K$.  Thus $u\in K$.

Comment: oh okay, thanks for your assistance Joe

Answer (score 0):

$v$ is a member of $H$, means $v$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $m_1,m_2,...,m_r$ and $u$. Let $v=c_1m_1+...+c_rm_r+cu$. Here, $c\neq0$ as $v\notin M$. Thus $u=c^{-1}(v-c_1m_1-...-c_rm_r)$. Hence, $u\in K$.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ANSWERING!. Question though, how do you know that value of u is a member of K?

Comment: As $K$ is spanned by $B_m$ and $v$ and $u$ is now a linear combination of members from $B_m$ and $v$.

Comment: oh! thank you. You are very smart